# Chrome transition bug on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

How to fix a bug in Chrome `transition` on `:hover`? Some `:hover` normally, and then does not work. Maybe I need jQuery solution?

I give an example, all whether there is such a bug when `transition`:

```css
.item {
    background: rgba(106, 204, 201, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6accc9', endColorstr='#6db1f4', GradientType=0);
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
}

.item:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.item:hover .title {
    transform: translate(0, -20px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -20px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -20px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="title">title1</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="title">title2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What bug? Can you describe it

Comment: in chrome :hover at just 10 times does not work transition

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, 10 times what? The only issue i see currently is `.title {position:absolyte;`

Comment: https://youtu.be/R652u3GM1x4

Comment: Thx for the video but i don't get this behaviour on chrome win7. Now i guess, firstly you should fix `position:absolyte;`, `absolute`, not `absolyte`. Then set transition for only specific property, don't use `all`  EDIT: ok, i'm able to replicate issue finally

Comment: https://youtu.be/wFOtk4cMP7c 
Unfortunately the problem is not solved

Comment: What behavior do you expect? Describe in detail please.

Comment: Always fires to transition.
The video shows a bug

Comment: Does it fix your issue on your side: http://jsfiddle.net/q3fa8fbL/

Comment: tnx. I use your option

Comment: @A.Wolff then you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/ktdxs5jy/):

```css
.item {
    background: rgba(106, 204, 201, 1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(106, 204, 201, 1) 0%, rgba(109, 177, 244, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6accc9', endColorstr='#6db1f4', GradientType=0);
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

    .item:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }

.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

    .item:hover .title {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
        -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
        -o-transform: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="title">title1</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="title">title2</div>
</div>
```

Don't see any bugs in latest Chrome (*Version 44.0.2403.130*) on OS X 10.10.4 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: thanks for the help. but in my browser all the same you get this error. I can not assume that it can be. 
I did as advised above
`transition: top 1s ease-in-out;`

Comment: @OsadchiyYuriy which browser/OS versions do you use?

Comment: last Chrome / OS X 10.10.3

Comment: @OsadchiyYuriy Retina display?

Comment: @OsadchiyYuriy it's strange. Using `transition: top` is worse by performance than `transition: transform` — http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/.